# Spring Boot pass file through form

Tags: html, spring-boot, file

I need to take a file from an input on my html, right now it looks like this:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="image" accept="image/*">
```

In my Controller I have the following:

```
...controller(@RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file, @Validated Object o, ...)
```

The main problem is that this **file** is always null, even if I do upload a file.

I have also tried placing it inside the validated object, but then I get an error that says that the file is a String and it could not be converted to MultipartFile.

(Just in case, im using spring-boot 2.7.9, not 3.0)

Is there any way of having this file work in the same controller as the Validated object?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Turns out the solution is very simple.
You just need to pass the parameter like this in the controller:

```
  @RequestParam(value = "image", required = false) MultipartFile file
```

And then add to the form in which your input is the following enctype:

```
   <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```